# Linq Object Array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am having some trouble in querying an object array using LINQ. I want to retrieve all products that contains the value passed.

My Product class

```
public class Product
{
    public int mProductId;
    public string mProductName;
    public string mProductColor;
    public string mProductSize;
    public string mProductStatus;
    public string mProductCode;

    public int ProductId{ get { return mProductId; }}
    public string ProductName { get{return mProductName; }}
    public string ProductColor { get{return mProductColor;} }
    public string ProductSize { get{return mProductSize;} }
    public string ProductStatus { get{return mProductStatus;} }
    public string ProductCode {get { return mProductCode; }}
}

public class ProductList
{
    public static Product[] mProductList = {
        new Product { mProductId = Resource.Drawable.Product1,
            mProductName = "Green Lumberjack Cap",
            mProductColor = "Color Brown",
            mProductSize = "One Size Fits All",
            mProductCode= "9780201760439",
            mProductStatus= "In Stock"},
        new Product { mProductId = Resource.Drawable.Product2,
            mProductName = "Square Bar stool", 
            mProductColor= "Color Brown",
            mProductSize = "One Size Fits All",
            mProductCode= "9780201760440",
            mProductStatus= "In Stock"},
        new Product { mProductId = Resource.Drawable.Product3,
            mProductName = "Vitra bathroom Tile",
            mProductColor= "Color Brown",
            mProductSize = "One Size Fits All",
            mProductCode= "9780201760539",
            mProductStatus= "In Stock"},


    };

    private Product[] mProducts;
    Random mRandom;

    public ProductList ()
    {
        mProducts = mProductList;

    }

    // Return the number of photos in the photo album:
    public int NumPhotos 
    { 
        get { return mProducts.Length; } 
    }

    // Indexer (read only) for accessing a photo:
    public Product this[int i] 
    {
        get { return mProducts[i]; }
    }

    // Pick a random photo and swap it with the top:
    public int RandomSwap()
    {
        // Save the photo at the top:
        Product tmpProduct = mProducts[0];

        // Generate a next random index between 1 and 
        // Length (noninclusive):
        int rnd = mRandom.Next(1, mProducts.Length);

        // Exchange top photo with randomly-chosen photo:
        mProducts[0] = mProducts[rnd];
        mProducts[rnd] = tmpProduct;

        // Return the index of which photo was swapped with the top:
        return rnd;
    }

    // Shuffle the order of the photos:
    public void Shuffle ()
    {  
        // Use the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm:
        for (int idx = 0; idx < mProducts.Length; ++idx)
        {
            // Save the photo at idx:
            Product tmpProduct = mProducts[idx];

            // Generate a next random index between idx (inclusive) and 
            // Length (noninclusive):
            int rnd = mRandom.Next(idx, mProducts.Length);

            // Exchange photo at idx with randomly-chosen (later) photo:
            mProducts[idx] = mProducts[rnd];
            mProducts[rnd] = tmpProduct;
        }
    }



}
```

and my LINQ statement is

```
var result = from p in nProductList<Product> 
                    where ( p.mProductName.Contains(query) || p.mProductColor.Contains(query))
            select p;
```

I have also declared nProductList in my class as

```
public ProductList nProductList;
```

It will be really great to know what am I doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: It would also be great if you read [ask]. Specifically read about MCVE

Comment: You need to expose the `mProducts` field publicly somehow - the safest is to add a get-only `IEnumerable<Product>` that returns an enumerator for the array (not the array itself since malicious code could cast to an array and modify it).

Comment: @Amit : Will be happy to make any changes in the way I ask. But could you please tell me what was i doing incorrect. I have read through that document and nothing did really strike me

Comment: what goes wrong? does it compile? does it run but give the wrong data? crash?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `where` keyword syntax to work, your `ProductList` class must have a `Where(Func<Product, bool>)` method on it. Most lists get this automatically because they implement `IEnumerable<>`, and the `System.Linq` namespace has a `Where()` extension method which matches this signature.

You could make `ProductList` implement the `IEnumerable<Product>` interface, or make it extend a class like `List<Product>` which already implements that interface, or add your own `Where()` method. However, I'd personally suggest that you just expose `mProductList` as an `IEnumerable<Product>` via a public property getter, and change your consuming code to query against that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your linq statement does not work is because you did not define where.  Imagine the old style linq:

```
nProductList.Where(p=>p.mProductName.Contains(query) || p.mProductColor.Contains(query)).Select(p=>);
```

nProductList does not have Where(Func) defined so it does not work.

Normally for your `ProductList` there are two ways to implement.  First way is to inherit from `IEnumerable<Product>` as `ProductList : IEnumerable<Product>`; 
Second way is to create a member in `ProductList` and make it public like

```
public class ProductList
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get; private set;}
    ...
}
```

Usually the preferable way between the two above will depends on is there more properties or more methods in your ProductList class.  More methods goes to the first way because it's more like an expended method collection of IEnumerable class (like your example), while more properties goes to the seconding way as this is more like another class just having a list in it and something else.